# Trying to use Javascript to hide "IWS" link when the site point to certain country e.g SG or ZA based on the URL

Tags: javascript, html

Need to know how to hide the link "IWS" when accessing to certain country base on URL

www.xxx.com/US/en - it will show up IWS link
www.xxx.com/SG/en - it will hide up IWS link

```html
<div class="linklist-title">Policy &amp; Services</div>
<div class="linklist"><a href="~/link.aspx?_id=F7A4FEE4CBD8412EB10A306E0365E7FA&amp;_z=z">IWS</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://.com">PS</a>
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=38E81630FCC44D8AA3121DA50ED869B6&amp;_z=z">WSP</a>
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=0B3497582DFD41F6BF84188D996C8BCB&amp;_z=z">WSA</a>
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=65578355653E4B8880DB9BAF93AE2A71&amp;_z=z">ACC</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery? If so, try something like:

```
if(location.href.match(/sg/i)) {
    $('.linklist:contains("IWS")').hide();
}
```

You should think about using a more generalized title for this kind of issue.